# Java JFrame removeall hangs an application

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jframe, event-dispatch-thread

I have the following code:

```
ActionListener listenerComboVehicle = new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        comboVehicle.removeActionListener(listenerComboVehicle);
        frameCrewSelection.removeAll();
        frameCrewSelection.add(formCrewSelectionForm(SpaceObjectArray.findMannedByName(comboVehicle.getSelectedItem().toString()))); //Create some controls (Jcombobox comboVehicle included) and assign listeners to them.
        formComboCrews(); //Modify JCombobox controls content
    }
};
```

And my application hangs on the following code in `EventDispatchThread.java`:

```
void pumpEventsForFilter(int id, Conditional cond, EventFilter filter) {
    addEventFilter(filter);
    while (doDispatch && cond.evaluate()) {
        if (isInterrupted() || !pumpOneEventForFilters(id)) {
            doDispatch = false;
        }
    }
    removeEventFilter(filter);
}
```

The while loop is infinite and it hangs my application. When `.removeAll()` is absent, the application doesn't hang but I get new controls over old controls. I've found a workaround by disposing a frame and creating it again but it looks nasty. Additional code will be provided if needed. Please help.

Comment: I wonder if your `removeAll()` removes the JFrame's JRootPane, GlassPane, and contentPane. Why not swap views with a CardLayout rather than manually add and remove components? Also, should this JFrame be a JDialog instead?

Comment: i've tried .setContentPane instead of remove/add and it behaves the same. Adding components has a reason - each element of comboVehicle combobox should have different number of controls. Yes, it's better be a JDialog sometimes in the future.

Comment: Thanks for CardLayout though. It's interesting but I don't think it fits perfectly.

Comment: I'm betting that you're doing something that goes against Swing's threading rules and that the problem lies in code not shown.

Comment: I've had an issue in Java 7 where calling `removeAll` on the frame caused a nasty repaint issue (sounds exactly what HoverCraftFullOfEels described).  Have you tried `frameCrewSelection.getContentPane().removeAll()` instead?  I'd also systematically comment out the two following lines (after the `removeAll`) and see if that makes a difference, may highlight another problem

Comment: I think JFrame.removeAll() to remove RootPane in Java6 too....

Comment: *"CardLayout .. It's interesting but I don't think it fits perfectly."*  Why not?

Comment: Thanks, `frameCrewSelection.getContentPane().removeAll();            frameCrewSelection.setContentPane(formCrewSelectionForm(SpaceObjectArray.findMannedByName(comboVehicle.getSelectedItem().toString())));` make it work.

Comment: CardLayout is not perfect because by design the feature of selecting item in this combobox is an additional and I think that it will not be used frequently. So no need to create controls in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved from comments for better view:

`frameCrewSelection.getContentPane().removeAll(); frameCrewSelection.setContentPane(formCrewSelectionForm(SpaceObjectArray.findMan‌​nedByName(comboVehicle.getSelectedItem().toString())));`

made it work.