# Panel components disappear when I minimize frame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I have a layout with a main panel whose content is decided by me throught buttons in this way:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    mainPanel.removeAll(); //removing all current panel components
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("content1")){
        mainPanel = new Content1Panel();
        add(mainPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        validate();
    }else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("content2")){
        mainPanel = new Content2Panel();
        add(mainPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        validate();
            }
}
```

now, if I minimize the frame and then bring it to front I find all main panel's components disappeared! Anyway, when I hover on them with the mouse components show again.
What is wrong?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Comment: `removeAll();`  Use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) instead.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12042039/1076463) where `removeAll` removed a bit too much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- for `JFrame` / `JDialog` / `JWindow`

to use

```
validate(); (revalidate in Java7 )
repaint();
```

- [example about standard rulles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6989230/714968)
- use `CardLayout` instead of `remove` and then `add` the `JPanel` to the container